# SAP Cloud SDK for javascript using the destination

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry, s4hana

I have followed the [Tutorial](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdkjs-deploy-application-cloud-foundry.html) and build the basic CF based nodejs applciation to display all BusinessPartners from my S/4HANA on-premise destination.

```
function getAllBusinessPartners(): Promise<BusinessPartner[]> {
  return BusinessPartner.requestBuilder()
    .getAll()
    .execute({
      destinationName: 'MockServer'
    });
}
```

Destination is configured with the Virtual host from cloud connector.

But after deploying to the Cloud Foundry, i get following error for the GET request

> {"message":"Service of type destination is not supported! Consider providing your own transformation function when calling destinationForServiceBinding, like this:\n  destinationServiceForBinding(yourServiceName, { serviceBindingToDestination: yourTransformationFunction });","level":"warn","custom_fields":{"package":"core","messageContext":"destination-accessor"},"logger":"sap-cloud-sdk-logger","timestamp":"2020-03-09T18:15:41.856Z","msg":"Service of type destination is not supported! Consider providing your own transformation function when calling destinationForServiceBinding, like this:\n  destinationServiceForBinding(yourServiceName, { serviceBindingToDestination: yourTransformationFunction });","written_ts":1583777741856,"written_at":"2020-03-09T18:15:41.856Z"}

The application is already bound to the Destination service as well.

Can someone help me here, what went wrong ? or the approach to use destination is different in the new version of Cloud-SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of attempts, i have made this to work.

**My Observations:**

1. `Connectivity` service is also required to be bound, when using on-premise S4 backend.
2. There was no errors in the log, i have made certain modification in the code to use `async/await`

```js
async function getAllBusinessPartners(): Promise<BusinessPartner[]> {
  return await BusinessPartner.requestBuilder()
    .getAll()
    .execute({
      destinationName: 'MockServer'
    });
}
```

After this modification, when I hit the GET request, it gave me the following error:

> "Failed to get business partners - get request to http://s4h-scc-basic:500/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER failed!"

Could notice that the `suffix` after the `http://domain:port` is twice. One I gave in the destination, and the other `VDM` adds automatically.
Ideally, this error is supposed to be thrown even before adding `async/await`.

After removing the `suffix` from the destination, it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

If your request really does error, what you posted here from your logs is most likely not the reason for the failure. We are aware that this message is confusing and will improve it (https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/pull/32).
Can you check whether there are more errors in your logs? Based on the code you posted and the setup you described, this should work. Do you have a binding to the XSUAA service.

Comment: Hi Dennis, there is no other error in the logs. yes, i have bound XSUAA and Destination service instance.

Comment: There's no other error in the logs, but when you access the for which you posted your code here, you still get an error? Can you somehow share your code? I'm out of ideas, from the top of my head...

Comment: i have put the code in github - https://github.com/navinkrishnan/cloud-sdk-node-s4ems.git pls check

Comment: I have taken a look at your code, three comments: 1) you're missing a binding to the destination service 2) the `MockServer` is not a CF service you can bind your application to 3) in your `getBusinessPartners` function your passing `jwt: "my-jwt"` as part of the parameter, which will not work. The JWT requested here is the user's access token. Since your app does not allow users to log in, you can simply omit this parameter, you do not need it.

Comment: Thank you for the observation. 1) My destination service instance and the destination, both i have given same name as "MockServer". what you mean by missing binding ? i have given the dest service instance name (Mockserver) in manifest.yml. where else is expected ? 3) i have removed the jwt:"my-jwt", still the same error

Comment: If `MockServer` is your destination service, then ignore my comment. If there's an error, there must either be some log or something you see when you call the route in your browser? Can you share a screenshot or something? I'm honestly of out of ideas.